# Selenium version 114.0.5735.16 not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.16').install()), options=options)
```

I have been using this code with selenium version `114.0.5735.16` up until recently however today I received the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

I have tried upgrading selenium in terminal and changing my code to use the new `116` but I get a different error message `There is no such driver by url`

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** Looks like you are not using the latest version of selenium which is `v4.11.2`. If you have chrome version `116`, then minimum supported selenium web driver is `4.11.2`

**Fix:** Since you are on chrome version `116`, upgrade your selenium version to `v4.11.2`, this issue should be resolved.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927754/7598774

Answer (score 0):

I am using java language. For java selenium v4.11.0 is latest. Before updating make sure your market place (in my case its eclipse) is working fine. and update in pom.xml to selenium latest version. and once the project is build I tried to verify dependency is reflecting properly. if the dependency is added then you should not be having any issues. you need not have any chrome driver and and browser(both will be downloaded if the respective version is not available in your system).